# Get non duplicate Rows From This Query Without using distinct keyword

Tags: sql-server

I need to filter out distinct rows from below query without using distinct keyword.

So in the CM.PfmFolderMstIpMap Table there are duplicate F.Id's or PMMAP.PfmFolderFK Id's so I want to filter out non-duplicate ones

```
    SELECT  F.Id,
                     F.folderno, 
                     F.folderstatusdate, 
                    (SELECT codedesc 
                     FROM   cm.codetable 
                     WHERE  id = F.FolderStatusCode) 'FolderStatus', 
                    (SELECT codedesc 
                     FROM   cm.codetable 
                     WHERE  id = F.FolderLocationCode) 'Location', 
                    F.volume, 
                    F.sdexhibits, 
                    F.cost, 
                    F.remarks 
    FROM   cm.pfmfolder F WITH(nolock) 
           INNER JOIN cm.pfmfoldermstipmap PMMAP WITH(nolock) 
                   ON PMMAP.pfmfolderfk = F.id 
           INNER JOIN cm.mstip MST WITH(nolock) 
                   ON MST.id = PMMAP.mstipfk 
           LEFT JOIN tm.mstirsdmstipmap IRMAP WITH(nolock) 
                  ON IRMAP.mstipfk = MST.id 
           LEFT JOIN tm.mstirsd IRSD WITH(nolock) 
                  ON IRSD.id = IRMAP.mstirsdfk 
           LEFT JOIN tm.mstir IR WITH(nolock) 
                  ON IR.id = IRSD.mstirfk 
           LEFT JOIN tm.mstiabasicmark IABM 
                  ON IABM.basicmarknbr = MST.applnnbr 
           LEFT JOIN tm.mstia IA 
                  ON IA.id = IABM.mstiafk 
    WHERE  ( @FolderNbr IS NULL 
              OR F.folderno LIKE + @FolderNbr + '%' ) 
           AND ( @ApplnNbr IS NULL 
                  OR MST.applnnbr LIKE + @ApplnNbr + '%' ) 
           AND ( @IrNbr IS NULL 
                  OR IR.irnbr LIKE + @IrNbr + '%' ) 
           AND ( @IaNbr IS NULL 
                  OR IA.ianbr LIKE + @IaNbr + '%' ) 
           AND ( @FolderStatusCode IS NULL 
                  OR F.folderstatuscode = @FolderStatusCode ) 
           AND ( @FolderLocationCode IS NULL 
                  OR F.folderlocationcode = @FolderLocationCode ) 
           AND ( F.folderstatusdate >= @FolderStatusDateFrom 
                 AND F.folderstatusdate < @FolderStatusDateTo ) 
           AND MST.registrycode = @RegistryCode 
           AND PMMAP.deletedby IS NULL
```

Comment: What is the reason why you don't want to use distinct?

Comment: It's causing slow performance if I using distinct because there are nearly 300K records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sam said Distinct is the best option. Otherwise use Group by using all columns

You can use Row_Number feature too

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT  F.Id,
                     F.folderno, 
                     F.folderstatusdate, 
                    (SELECT codedesc 
                     FROM   cm.codetable 
                     WHERE  id = F.FolderStatusCode) 'FolderStatus', 
                    (SELECT codedesc 
                     FROM   cm.codetable 
                     WHERE  id = F.FolderLocationCode) 'Location', 
                    F.volume, 
                    F.sdexhibits, 
                    F.cost, 
                    F.remarks,
                    Row_number() OVER(partition BY F.Id  ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) ASC) RN              
    FROM   cm.pfmfolder F WITH(nolock) 
           INNER JOIN cm.pfmfoldermstipmap PMMAP WITH(nolock) 
                   ON PMMAP.pfmfolderfk = F.id 
           INNER JOIN cm.mstip MST WITH(nolock) 
                   ON MST.id = PMMAP.mstipfk 
           LEFT JOIN tm.mstirsdmstipmap IRMAP WITH(nolock) 
                  ON IRMAP.mstipfk = MST.id 
           LEFT JOIN tm.mstirsd IRSD WITH(nolock) 
                  ON IRSD.id = IRMAP.mstirsdfk 
           LEFT JOIN tm.mstir IR WITH(nolock) 
                  ON IR.id = IRSD.mstirfk 
           LEFT JOIN tm.mstiabasicmark IABM 
                  ON IABM.basicmarknbr = MST.applnnbr 
           LEFT JOIN tm.mstia IA 
                  ON IA.id = IABM.mstiafk 
    WHERE  ( @FolderNbr IS NULL 
              OR F.folderno LIKE + @FolderNbr + '%' ) 
           AND ( @ApplnNbr IS NULL 
                  OR MST.applnnbr LIKE + @ApplnNbr + '%' ) 
           AND ( @IrNbr IS NULL 
                  OR IR.irnbr LIKE + @IrNbr + '%' ) 
           AND ( @IaNbr IS NULL 
                  OR IA.ianbr LIKE + @IaNbr + '%' ) 
           AND ( @FolderStatusCode IS NULL 
                  OR F.folderstatuscode = @FolderStatusCode ) 
           AND ( @FolderLocationCode IS NULL 
                  OR F.folderlocationcode = @FolderLocationCode ) 
           AND ( F.folderstatusdate >= @FolderStatusDateFrom 
                 AND F.folderstatusdate < @FolderStatusDateTo ) 
           AND MST.registrycode = @RegistryCode 
           AND PMMAP.deletedby IS NULL 
) AS T
WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Distinct is the best option. Otherwise use Group by using all columns

Comment: I am only selecting some columnns , cannot use groupby

Comment: I meant use those columns that you are selecting to group by

Comment: I tried out but taking 11S to execute 400K records...Any other faster way to fix this

Comment: Did you check the execution plan? You have too many joins. Break them up to sub queries. and, try to get the unique records in these sub queries. Start with execution plan. All the best!

Comment: Don't worry about the no of records. DBMSs are meant to handle that kind of a load ;-)

Comment: You could do one more thing to improve the performance. I.e. use temp tables to hold sub queries (keep two or three max joins in one sub query). Then join those temp tables. This is a trick we use to handle large data sets. Write your query in different ways and look at the execution plan. You'll understand then.